# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que utiliza HTML, JS, PHP e MySQL.
As páginas possuem várias chamadas AJAX para o banco.
Tenho hoje aproximadamente 350 usuários.

Ultimamente venho recebendo muitos erros de:

- `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
- `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
- E outros.

Os usuários também estão tendo esses problemas.

Uma visão básica do meu sistema:

- O sistema está hospedado no `LOCAWEB`
- Utilizo `SESSION`
- Todas as consultas estão localizadas em arquivos PHP separados, conforme minha necessidade.
- Existem algumas funções que utilizam `file_get_contents()`, pois preciso buscar dados dos usuários em outro site.
- Todas as paginas têm seu próprio arquivo JS para separas as funções que preciso.
- Utilizo o tema `ADMINLTE` como base.

Pergunto:

- Qual a relação desses erros com meu sistema?
- Seria alguma configuração errada no `PHP.INI`?

OBS: pra teste local, utilizo o WAMP, e nunca tive problemas.

Comment: No log do apache aparece alguma coisa? Os erros indicam sobrecarga do servidor, agora em qual ponto não tem como saber.

Comment: No log do LOCAWEB, tem muitos desses erros:
mod_mime_magic: invalid type 0 in mconvert()

Comment: vc usa o `file_get_contents()` para 'conectar' e pegar informaçoes de outros sites?

Comment: Sim. Acabei de ver outro erro:
ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete

Comment: vc precisa isolar o problema, verifique os arquivos ou funções que usam o `file_get_contents()`, ele vai depender do tempo de resposta do servidor da localweb fazer requisição com o outro site, por padrão uma requisição dura 30 segundo mais que isso, o script é abortado.

Comment: Eu setei:
max_input_time = -1
e
max_execution_time = 3600
Para testes.

Comment: O site externo pode também bloquear o ip do servidor, achando que é uma tentativa de flood ou ataque de negação de serviço, que consiste em enviar um número grande requisições que o servidor não consiga tratar.

Answer (score 0):

Com apenas as informações passadas não dá para dar uma resposta conclusiva do que pode estar causando a lentidão no sistema, mas podemos analisar ponto a ponto sobre a sua visão básica do seu sistema para te ajudar a descobrir e corrigir o problema:

**- O sistema está hospedado no LOCAWEB**

Não cabe a mim falar mal ou bem da Locaweb, mas teste em outro servidor e se no outro servidor não der mais erro, problema resolvido.

**- Utilizo SESSION**

Não vejo relação de problema de lentidão com uso de session, pule pra próxima.

**- Todas as consultas estão localizadas em arquivos PHP separados, conforme minha necessidade.**

É indiferente o número de arquivos utilizados. Pule pra próxima.

**- Existem algumas funções que utilizam file_get_contents(), pois preciso buscar dados dos usuários em outro site.**

Se o site externo estiver lento ou bloqueando seu IP, aí pode estar o seu problema. Tente isolar esse código, testá-lo e se possível veja uma alternativa pra isso, como usar um webservice desse site externo ou ter um usuário seu acessando o banco de dados do site externo - Tudo vai depender da sua relação com o responsável por esse site externo.

**Todas as paginas têm seu próprio arquivo JS para separas as funções que preciso.**

Indiferente. Pule pra próxima.

**Utilizo o tema ADMINLTE como base.**

Indiferente também.

**As páginas possuem várias chamadas AJAX para o banco.**

Veja de quanto em quanto tempo você faz essas chamadas ajax. Banco de dados é um recurso custoso. Embora o uso de ajax por si só não tenha nenhum impacto em velocidade, verifique suas queries. Às vezes você pode estar consultando mais coisa do que precisa, é bom usar LIMIT nas queries, limitando o número de registros retornados, além de pôr índices para os campos usados nas cláusulas WHERE.